# Class path must be set or restored default

Tags: java, hibernate

I was doing a Hibernate project while creating pojo I am getting this error "Class path must be set or restored default"  while doing console configuration I have all the jars which are working with other projects please help me with this

Comment: Where did you get that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error mainly appears when some jars or sql drivers is missing. You said that you have added all the jars, but try to check it again carefully. If your jars is placed not in your project so you need to check if they still exist in specified path. It's recommended to copy them to the project folder first and then add them by 'add jar' (if you using eclipse).

I hope it helps. But you can give more details to understand what real problem is.